# onActivityResult not being called after return from activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm going from fragment that is in activity MainActivity to activity SetExperimentActivity like this:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), SetExperimentActivity.class);
myIntent.putExtra(SetExperimentActivity.KEY_RESERVATION_END, reservation.getEndAsDate());
getActivity().startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
getActivity().overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
```

In the MainActivity I have the onActivityResult method

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    this.intent = data;
}
```

In the SetExperimentActivity I make some operations and redirect back to MainActivity with extra parcelable like this:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent();
myIntent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_EQUIPMENT, equipment);
setResult(0, myIntent);
finish();
```

The onActivityResult is not being called

Comment: getIntent never returns null

Answer (score 1):

In that case, you should use `startActivityForResult`, not `startActivity`! Refer the official documentation given on [Getting a Result from an Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html).

Comment: So I set - myIntent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_EQUIPMENT, equipment); .... setResult(0, myIntent); .... finish(); it returns back to the MainActivity but my onActivityResult is not called

Comment: where are you calling onActivityResult?

Comment: in MainActivity class where the startActivityForResult is called to call the other activity

Answer (score 0):

`startactivityforresult` method is call in your first activity  then after fill the data in second activity we can use the `setresult(RESULT_OK,data);` Then after call the `onactivityresult`enter code here in your first activity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
// Check which request we're responding to
if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST) {
    // Make sure the request was successful
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // The user picked a contact.
        // The Intent's data Uri identifies which contact was selected.

        // Do something with the contact here (bigger example below)
    }
}
}
```